# How to show $X$ is continuously embedded into $\mathcal{C}$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Set $$W=\Big\{ u:[0,+\infty )\to \mathbb{R} \; \text{is absolutely continuous and}\; u'\in L^2 [0,+\infty)\Big\},$$ where $q$ is a non-zero constant. Assume that $$X=\Big\{ u\in W:\int_0^{+\infty}(|u'(t)|^2+q^2 |u(t)|^2)dt<+\infty\Big\}$$ with the inner product $$\langle u,v\rangle:=\int_0^{+\infty}(u'(t)v'(t)+q^2u(t)v(t))dt$$ which induces the norm $$\|u\|:=\Big( \int_0^{+\infty}(|u'(t)|^2+q^2 |u(t)|^2)dt\Big)^{\frac{1}{2}}$$.

I was wondering if someone could tell me how I can show that $X$ is continuously embedded into $\mathcal{C}$, where $$\mathcal{C}=\{ u\in C([0,+\infty)):\| u\|_{\infty}<\infty \}.$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A stronger conclusion can be derived. Namely
$$X\subset \{u\in C[0,\infty)\:\, \lim_{x\to \infty}u(x)=0\},\quad \|u\|_\infty\le \max\{1,q^{-1}\}\|u\|$$
We have $$(u^2)'=2uu'$$ For $x_2>x_1\ge 0$ we get $$|u^2(x_2)-u^2(x_1)|=2\left |\int\limits_{x_1}^{x_2}u(t)u'(t)\,dt\right | \le 2\int\limits_{x_1}^{x_2}|u(t)u'(t)|\,dt\\ \le \int\limits_{x_1}^{x_2}[u(t)^2+u'(t)^2]\,dt \le \int\limits_{x_1}^\infty[u(t)^2+u'(t)^2]\,dt \\
\le \max\{1,q^{-2}\}\left [\int\limits_{x_1}^\infty[u(t)^2+q^2u'(t)^2]\,dt \right ]\underset{x_1\to \infty}{\longrightarrow} 0$$ Hence the Cauchy condition for the existence of the limit $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to \infty}u^2(x)$ is satisfied. The limit is nonnegative. It cannot be positive
as the function $u^2$ is integrable. Thus
$$\lim_{x\to \infty}u(x)^2=0$$ Letting $x_2\to \infty$ and substituting $x_1:=x,$ in the inequality
$$ |u^2(x_2)-u^2(x_1)|\le  \max\{1,q^{-2}\}\left [\int\limits_{x_1}^\infty[u(t)^2+q^2u'(t)^2\right ]\,dt$$ gives
$$u^2(x)\le \max\{1,q^{-2}\}\int\limits_{x}^\infty[u(t)^2+q^2u'(t)^2]\,dt\\ \le \max\{1,q^{-2}\}\int\limits_{0}^\infty[u(t)^2+q^2u'(t)^2]\,dt=\max\{1,q^{-2}\}\|u\|^2$$
Thus
$$\|u\|_\infty\le \max\{1,q^{-1}\}\,\|u\|$$

Comment: Dear @RyszardSzwarc , thank you so much for your answer and help. I have some question: How do we get from $|u^2(x_2 )-u^2 (x_1)|\to 0$ as $x_1 \to \infty$ to the fact that the limit $\lim_{x\to \infty}{u(x)^2}$ exists? Also, how do we get from integrability of $u^2$ to $\lim_{x\to \infty}{u(x)^2}=0$? What is the use of $\lim_{x\to \infty}{u(x)^2}=0$?

Comment: Dear M. Ramana I have re-edited. Should be clearer now. If $\lim_{x\to +\infty} f(x)=a>0$ the integral $\int_b^\infty f(x)\,dx $ is divergent to $+\infty$ as $f(x)\ge a/2$ for $x$ large enough.

Comment: Thanks very much. I got it completely. Appreciate that.